# Where is checksumValid() defined?

Tags: rust, rustup

I am working from a compliance perspective. I am struggling with the simplest thing, how to find the source for various functions that are called by rustup.

For example, the [rustup source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/blob/5225e87a5d974ab5f1626bcb2a7b43f76ab883f0/src/dist/notifications.rs#L20) references checksumValid, but I can't find it defined anywhere. I searched stackoverflow, I searched Google, etc.

I'd appreciate help finding checksumValid, but more importantly, what is wrong with my approach?

```
pub enum Notification<'a> {
...
NoUpdateHash(&'a Path),
ChecksumValid(&'a str),
SignatureValid(&'a str, &'a PgpPublicKey),
...
```

Comment: This *is* the definition. `ChecksumValid` is a member of the enum `Notification<'a>`, carrying `&'a str` as its payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChecksumValid(&'a str)` here is not actually a function but rather one of many possible values of an enum `Notification` defined [in this line](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/blob/5225e87a5d974ab5f1626bcb2a7b43f76ab883f0/src/dist/notifications.rs#L12). While the `()` is usually associated with functions in rust it can denote other things as well. In this case it denotes one possible value of the enum that contains some data that is of type `&str` with a lifetime of `'a`. This is the *definition* of this value, in this line right here.

You might want to read [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html) to understand the syntax.

Comment: I see. I'm to think of checksumValid as a constant (a particular value for the enum), not a function.

Comment: Sort of. Each variable of type `Notification`  can have one out of finite possible values - `NoUpdateHash`, `ChecksumValid` or other that are defined, thats how enums work. Now, the parentheses `()` signify that IF the variable has value `ChecksumValid` it may also contain data which will be of type `&str`. On the other hand if its value is `NoUpdateHash` it may contain other data, that will be of type `&Path`. The `'a` in both cases is a lifetime which is a separate topic.